# How do I take the combinations of list elements?

Tags: python, list, combinations

I am trying to find out the combinations of elements without using any predefined library.
In below code , I am finding the combinations according to first element but I want to find out for every others too !

**Code:**

```
a = [20, 22, 30, 45, 50]
new_list = []
i = a[0]
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    new_list.append((a[i] , a[i + 1]))
new_list
```

**Output for just single element a[0]:**

```
[(20, 20), (20, 22), (20, 30), (20, 45), (20, 50)]
```

Expected_Output:

```
[(20, 22), (20, 30), (20, 45), (20, 50)]
[(22, 20), (22, 30), (22, 45), (22, 50)]
              .
              .
```

Comment: Any reason for not using predefined library? `itertools` is perfect for this case

Comment: It is the requirements that we cannot use any predefined library , otherwise it is too easy !

Comment: Nest the loop in another loop

Comment: a = [20, 22, 30, 45, 50];l = []; for i in a:    for j in a:         l +=[(i,j)]  ;   print(l)

Comment: Your answer is right , @VisheshMangla Thanks

Comment: That loop does not output what you show... Please post a proper [mre]

Comment: @VisheshMangla What if we don't want to take a pair of similar items like (20 , 20) , (22, 22) etc..

Comment: Check the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: just add an if i!=j . Better to go for range(len()) to reduce cycles but anyways.

Comment: Even after they said no library people are rushing behind itertools. So much strange !!

Comment: not a problem.  a = [20, 22, 30, 45, 50]
l = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
        l +=[(a[i],a[j])]
print(l)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution **without using any predefined library**

```
a = [20, 22, 30, 45, 50]
new_list = []

for i, item in enumerate(a):

    sub_list = []

    for j, second_item in enumerate(a):
        if i == j:
            continue
        sub_list.append((a[i] , a[j]))

    new_list.append(sub_list)

print(new_list)
```

The output will be:

```
[[(20, 22), (20, 30), (20, 45), (20, 50)],
[(22, 20), (22, 30), (22, 45), (22, 50)],
[(30, 20), (30, 22), (30, 45), (30, 50)],
[(45, 20), (45, 22), (45, 30), (45, 50)],
[(50, 20), (50, 22), (50, 30), (50, 45)]]
```

EDIT:
If you don't want duplicates like `(20, 22) (22,20)`, do that:

```
a = [20, 22, 30, 45, 50]
new_list = []

for i, item in enumerate(a):

    sub_list = []

    for j, second_item in enumerate(a):
        if i == j or j < i:
            continue
        sub_list.append((a[i] , a[j]))
    if sub_list != []:
        new_list.append(sub_list)

print(new_list)
```

And the output will be:

```
[[(20, 22), (20, 30), (20, 45), (20, 50)],
 [(22, 30), (22, 45), (22, 50)], [(30, 45), (30, 50)],
 [(45, 50)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = [20, 22, 30, 45, 50]
combined_list = []

for first_element in a:
    new_list = []
    for second_element in a:
        if first_element != second_element:
            new_list.append((first_element, second_element))

    combined_list.append(new_list)
```

Answer (score -3):

```py
from itertools import combinations
a = [20, 22, 30, 45, 50]
comb = combinations(a, 2)
 
lis_comb = []
for i in list(comb):
    lis_comb.append(i)
print(lis_comb)
```

```
  [(20, 22), (20, 30), (20, 45), (20, 50), (22, 30), (22, 45), (22, 50), (30, 45), (30, 50), (45, 50)]
```

Comment: He asked `without using any predefined library.`